# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p.id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to execute this query in laravel and it give me the

> error:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p.id' in 'field list' (SQL: `` select `p`.`id` as `post_id`, `title`, `post_content`, `image_dir`, `video_dir`, `p`.`created_at` as `post_date`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `profile_img` from `users` as `u,posts` where `title` like %mo% or `post_content` like %mo% order by `p`.`created_at` desc ``)

```
$posts= DB::table('users AS u,posts AS p')
    ->select('p.id as post_id','title','post_content','image_dir','video_dir','p.created_at as post_date','first_name','last_name','profile_img')
    ->where('title', 'like', "%{$key}%")
    ->orWhere('post_content', 'like', "%{$key}%")
    ->orderBy('p.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

my posts table

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->text('post_content')->nullable();
            $table->double('likes')->default(0);
            $table->double('dislikes')->default(0);
            $table->integer('size')->nullable();
            $table->string('image_dir')->nullable();
            $table->string('video_dir')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

my user table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('phone_number')->nullable();
            $table->string('location')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('profile_img')->nullable();
            $table->string('cover_img')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: You have to select one table. Tell me what are you going to do and I can help you.

Comment: As you can see the fragment `AS p` in `DB::table('users AS u,posts AS p')` was ignored. Maybe simply do not use an alias for `posts`? or try to use `CROSS JOIN` instead of comma.

Comment: Can you share your tables schema?

Comment: I want to retrieve the post date from the post table and use the foreign key user_id to retrieve the user name and profile image of the user who posted the post  from users table and send it with the rest of post data as one record.

Comment: @DonKnacki I edited my table schema into the post

Comment: I agree with the answer given : you should use a join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need an [`INNER JOIN`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inner-join-clause) clause:

```php
$posts= DB::table('users AS u')
    ->join('posts As p', 'u.id', '=', 'p.user_id' )
    ->select('p.id as post_id','title','post_content','image_dir','video_dir','p.created_at as post_date','first_name','last_name','profile_img')
    ->where('title', 'like', "%{$key}%")
    ->orWhere('post_content', 'like', "%{$key}%")
    ->orderBy('p.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```